# Hide/Open JTable by a press of a button in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I want to represent data split into groups (categories) and when pressing a button of a category I want `JTable` to show below category button. I've built `JScrollPane` on it is placed `JPanel` which is a container of costume made panels (`BoxLayout` is used for placement in the container).

[image]

Costume made panel (CMP) to show category with a function to hide or show `JTable`

Now the problem is when i press button to show or hide table function is executed in code of CMP but `JScrollPane` does not refresh and does not show the action. It refreshes when you click on scroll bar. What can i do about it? Is there any better way to build something like this?

Comment: Two thoughts come to mind; 1. Use a `CardLayout`; or better 2. Update the `TableModel` been used by the `JTable` itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm thinking more about moving `onClickFunction` of a button out of CMP to the code where I keep the container (`JPanel`) so than its viable to refresh `JScrollPane`. But still, i did not figure this out...

Comment: OK, i figured it out! What I did is change `JButton` and `JScrollPane` from private to protected in CMP, then access it from container `JPanel` to set action method in which I `.revalidate()` main `JScrollPane`. Now it works fine!